# Need help creating SQL query to most recent data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MS SQL Server express 2012 table that is constantly being populated with data to let us know which of our products are available. Under each product are one or many sub_products. When the process that updates the product does its update, it also updates all sub_products at the same time. (thus all will have the same founddate stamp because they were found in the same run)  Because this data is constantly being added to the table only the most recent data matters. We don’t want to delete the old data as it is used for other purposes but I need help creating a statement to help me view only the newest data for each product (including subproducts) The challenge is that we have thousands of products and subproducts and they will all have different “most recent found” times.

This sql fiddle is a very simplified version of what my data looks like:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0531b/1

I would like help creating a query that returns only the most recent founddate (and corresponding data) for each product. I would like the result of this query (using the data set in the fiddle) to look like this:

```
product sub_product founddate
1       1           5/3/2014
1       2           5/3/2014
2       7           5/4/2014
2       8           5/4/2014
2       9           5/4/2014
3       10          4/15/2014
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: +1 . . . A comment-less downvote on well-written question with a SQL Fiddle.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way to do this is with a `not exists` clause:

```
select *
from project_data pd
where not exists (select 1
                  from project_data pd2
                  where pd2.product = pd.product and
                        pd2.founddate > pd.founddate
                 );
```

The logic is:  "Get me all rows from `project_data` where the same product does not have a larger date."  This will perform best with an index on `project_data(product, founddate)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option joining the table to itself using `Max`:

```
select pd.product, pd.sub_product, pd.founddate
from project_data pd
  join (select product, max(founddate) maxdt
        from project_data
        group by product
        ) t on pd.product = t.product and pd.founddate = t.maxdt
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5d4e/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T2.product,T1.sub_product,T2.founddate
FROM project_data T1 INNER JOIN
(
  select product,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(datetime, max(founddate),   1), 101)as founddate 
  from project_data
  GROUP BY product
) T2 ON T1.founddate=T2.founddate AND T1.product=T2.product
ORDER BY T2.product,T1.sub_product
```

Result:

```
PRODUCT   SUB_PRODUCT   FOUNDDATE
1         1             05/03/2014
1         2             05/03/2014
2         7             05/04/2014
2         8             05/04/2014
2         9             05/04/2014
3         10            04/15/2014
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0531b/40).

**Explanation:**

The inner query select `product` and maximum `founddate` for each product. Then the table itself has been joined with the result set on `product` and `founddate` which is used to select the `sub_product` for each `product` and `founddate` in the result of inner query.